# Trying to find the minimum value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display the minimum value from AnnualBudget, here is the code I have done so far:

```
SELECT WARD.HospitalCode,
       HOSPITAL.HospitalCode Name,
       WardNo,
       AnnualBudget
FROM WARD,
     HOSPITAL
WHERE (AnnualBudget) =
    (SELECT AnnualBudget
     FROM WARD
     WHERE AnnualBudget =
         (SELECT MIN(AnnualBudget)
          FROM WARD
          WHERE AnnualBudget >
              (SELECT MIN(AnnualBudget)
               FROM WARD
          ) 
     )
);
```

However instead of selecting the minimum value it actually selects the maximum value, can anybody help?

Comment: Are your numbers actually negative values by accident?

Comment: The values in the table are all positive values, I'm really baffled as to why this is happening.

Comment: That's a pretty horrible set of nested subqueries. Surely there is a better way to rewrite them.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you something higher than the min

```
select min(annualbudget)
from ward
where annualbudget > (
  select min(annualbudget)
  from ward
)
```

If you want the min, try this: I don't much oracle these days, but it should work)

```
select (stuff)

from ward w
join hospital h on h.hospitalId = w.hostpitalId

where w.annualbudget = (select min(annualbudget) from ward)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be more like this?

```
SELECT W.HospitalCode, H.HospitalCode, Name, WardNo, AnnualBudget  
FROM WARD W, HOSPITAL H 
WHERE W.HospitalCode = H.HospitalCode
  and W.AnnualBudget = (Select MIN(AnnualBudget) FROM WARD W2 
                                                WHERE W2.HospitalCode = W.HospitalCode)
```

I assumed that hospitalcode in WARD is a foreign key and you want the wards per hospital with the lowest budget, right?

Comment: I'm just looking to get the WARD with the lowest budget to display through using sub queries, I tried what you wrote and it displayed the lowest and the second lowest.

Comment: I've sorted it myself, thanks for the help though!! Much aprecitaed.

Comment: Ended up with this, just changed all the W. and H. to WARD and HOSPITAL which did the trick.

Comment: SELECT WARD.HospitalCode, HOSPITAL.HospitalCode, Name, WardNo, AnnualBudget  
FROM WARD, HOSPITAL 
WHERE WARD.HospitalCode = HOSPITAL.HospitalCode
  and WARD.AnnualBudget = (Select MIN(AnnualBudget) FROM WARD 
                                                WHERE WARD.HospitalCode = WARD.HospitalCode);